# How can I make my Tumblr blog public?

Tags: tumblr, sharing

When I created **`nameOfBlog.tumblr.com`** I set it to require a password. I would now like to make it public.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you saying that your blog is private and you don't want it to be?

Comment: yeah, i want to share it. how to change it to public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change your blog to a public blog go here: `http://www.tumblr.com/blog/nameOfBlog/settings`

- Scroll to Password section (near the bottom)
- Uncheck the box labeled: "Password protect this blog"
- Click "Save"

Notes:

- I wasn't able to find this setting on my existing Tumblr blogs
- It may be that once you post something public you can't turn it back into private (unverified)

Comment: interesting information about private-public changes, thanks!